# MySQL: Extracting data from an unusually formatted XML file

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML file with entries that look like this:

```
<card name="Fire Toad" id="7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073">
    <property name="Sphere" value="Nature" />
    <property name="Cost" value="1" />
    <property name="Type" value="Creature" />
    <property name="Subtype" value="Animal Toad" />
    <property name="Attack" value="3" />
    <property name="Defense" value="2" />
    <property name="Gems" value="B" />
    <property name="Rules" value="" />
    <property name="Flavor" value="Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing." />
    <property name="Rarity" value="Common" />
    <property name="Series" value="1" />
    <property name="Number" value="106" />
    <property name="Illustrator" value="Kevin Shoemaker" />
</card>
```

I want to extract data from it (for each card: name, id, and all of the properties) and insert it into a table in a MySQL database. It would be great if I could use the built-in LOAD XML statement, but unfortunately it doesn't support my file's formatting. What would be the most convenient way to do this?

Comment: Is that the entire XML? Or are there other *cards* with an encompassing root? And do you use an application layer language (Python, Perl, VB, PHP, Java)?

Comment: This is just a small excerpt from the entire XML. There are various <card> nodes within a <cards> node. There are also other nodes, but none of them are of my interest for the sake of this database. And I am not using any application layer language.

Comment: Also, every card has the same properties – only the values vary.

Comment: `There are also other nodes, but none of them are of my interest for the sake of this database.` **BUT** they are of vital interest to understanding the XML file as a whole. e.g. Is the XML file "well formed"? Please don't make assumptions about what  we need to see from that file. You *can* remove repetition  of structures, but we need the whole xml "skeleton".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) which much like SQL is a declarative, special-purpose language but designed to transform XML sources to specific formats like the XML needed for MySQL's [LOAD XML](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) method. XSLT can be run by command line with Bash/Powershell, any general purpose language (Java, C#, PHP, Perl, Python, R, VB), dedicated processors like [Saxon/Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info), even your everyday Excel!

In fact you can even run XSLT directly from MySQL's command line client by sending a shell command to terminal. Here is an [`xsltproc`](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) (processor available for Linux/Mac) call:

```
mysql> \! xsltproc -o /path/to/Output.xml /path/to/Script.xsl /path/to/Input.xml
```

Below script parses down to *card* node and migrates *property* children to new element and value.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">  
        <data> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="cards"/>
        </data>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cards">  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="card"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="card"> 
        <row>
           <name><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></name>
           <id><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></id>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
        </row>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input XML** *(assuming a structure in this format, adjust root name in XSLT)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <more_nodes/>
  <still_nodes/>
  <cards>
    <card name="Fire Toad 1" id="7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073">
      <property name="Sphere" value="Nature 1"/>
      <property name="Cost" value="1"/>
      <property name="Type" value="Creature 1"/>
      <property name="Subtype" value="Animal Toad 1"/>
      <property name="Attack" value="3"/>
      <property name="Defense" value="2"/>
      <property name="Gems" value="B1"/>
      <property name="Rules" value=""/>
      <property name="Flavor" value="Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 1"/>
      <property name="Rarity" value="Common 1"/>
      <property name="Series" value="1"/>
      <property name="Number" value="106"/>
      <property name="Illustrator" value="Kevin Shoemaker 1"/>
    </card>
    <card name="Fire Toad 2" id="7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073">
      <property name="Sphere" value="Nature 2"/>
      <property name="Cost" value="1"/>
      <property name="Type" value="Creature 2"/>
      <property name="Subtype" value="Animal Toad 2"/>
      <property name="Attack" value="3"/>
      <property name="Defense" value="2"/>
      <property name="Gems" value="B2"/>
      <property name="Rules" value=""/>
      <property name="Flavor" value="Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 2"/>
      <property name="Rarity" value="Common 2"/>
      <property name="Series" value="1"/>
      <property name="Number" value="106"/>
      <property name="Illustrator" value="Kevin Shoemaker 2"/>
    </card>
    <card name="Fire Toad 3" id="7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073">
      <property name="Sphere" value="Nature 3"/>
      <property name="Cost" value="1"/>
      <property name="Type" value="Creature 3"/>
      <property name="Subtype" value="Animal Toad 3"/>
      <property name="Attack" value="3"/>
      <property name="Defense" value="2"/>
      <property name="Gems" value="B3"/>
      <property name="Rules" value=""/>
      <property name="Flavor" value="Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 3"/>
      <property name="Rarity" value="Common 3"/>
      <property name="Series" value="1"/>
      <property name="Number" value="106"/>
      <property name="Illustrator" value="Kevin Shoemaker 3"/>
    </card>
  </cards>
  <other_nodes/>
</root>
```

**Output XML** *(ready for MySQL's LOAD XML)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
  <row>
    <name>Fire Toad 1</name>
    <id>7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073</id>
    <Sphere>Nature 1</Sphere>
    <Cost>1</Cost>
    <Type>Creature 1</Type>
    <Subtype>Animal Toad 1</Subtype>
    <Attack>3</Attack>
    <Defense>2</Defense>
    <Gems>B1</Gems>
    <Rules/>
    <Flavor>Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 1</Flavor>
    <Rarity>Common 1</Rarity>
    <Series>1</Series>
    <Number>106</Number>
    <Illustrator>Kevin Shoemaker 1</Illustrator>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Fire Toad 2</name>
    <id>7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073</id>
    <Sphere>Nature 2</Sphere>
    <Cost>1</Cost>
    <Type>Creature 2</Type>
    <Subtype>Animal Toad 2</Subtype>
    <Attack>3</Attack>
    <Defense>2</Defense>
    <Gems>B2</Gems>
    <Rules/>
    <Flavor>Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 2</Flavor>
    <Rarity>Common 2</Rarity>
    <Series>1</Series>
    <Number>106</Number>
    <Illustrator>Kevin Shoemaker 2</Illustrator>
  </row>
  <row>
    <name>Fire Toad 3</name>
    <id>7366070c-c74d-4bb9-b3d8-23177e887073</id>
    <Sphere>Nature 3</Sphere>
    <Cost>1</Cost>
    <Type>Creature 3</Type>
    <Subtype>Animal Toad 3</Subtype>
    <Attack>3</Attack>
    <Defense>2</Defense>
    <Gems>B3</Gems>
    <Rules/>
    <Flavor>Fire toads have the uncanny ability to cook their food while chewing. 3</Flavor>
    <Rarity>Common 3</Rarity>
    <Series>1</Series>
    <Number>106</Number>
    <Illustrator>Kevin Shoemaker 3</Illustrator>
  </row>
</data>
```